# How do I prevent hibernate from dropping times from datetimes?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, struts, hibernate-mapping

I have an application that is using hibernate mappings to perform a select over multiple DATETIME columns in a SQL Server database table. The hibernate mapping takes this DATETIME and transforms it to a java.util.Date object in the application.

```
Database table

Start_time | datetime

10-OCT-2014 06:45:00
10-OCT-2014 13:30:00
```

The problem is that the times that are stored in the DATETIME fields in the database are being dropped/truncated and every date is returned with a time of 00:00 when hibernate is bringing them into the application:

Hibernate Column mapping:

```
.
.
<property name="start_dt" type="java.util.Date">
    <column name="Start_time"/>
</property>
.
```

I have it mapping to a date object with the proper getters/setters and my query execution looks like this:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT Start_time FROM table")
   .addScalar("Start_time", Hibernate.Date)
   .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Class.class);
```

I am getting this:

```
List<Date> = { '10/10/2014 00:00' , '10/10/2014 00:00' }
```

What I want is this:

```
List<Date> = { '10/10/2014 06:45:00' , '10/10/2014 13:30:00' }
```

The application is doing something similar with an Oracle connection and it is returning the times successfully. The only variable is that my connection is to a SQL Server database. Does anyone know how to prevent the times from being dropped?

UPDATE:

Based on the selected answer bleow and because the comment isn't showing correctly the fix for this is the following:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT Start_time FROM table")
   .addScalar("Start_time", Hibernate.TIMESTAMP)
   .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Class.class);
```

Comment: The situation code is not taken from the application but generic to explain the situation. Also the Oracle process mapping to columns of the DATE datatype and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use timestamp

```
<property name="start_dt" type="timestamp">
    <column name="Start_time"/>
</property>
```

ANSI SQL DATE doesn't contain time

Mapping type: date
Java type: java.util.Date or java.sql.Date
ANSI SQL Type:DATE

Mapping type: timestamp
Java type: java.util.Date or java.sql.Timestamp
ANSI SQL Type: TIMESTAMP

Comment: No this isn't working either I just made the configuration change and ran it and it it still returning the date with truncated times

Comment: I the solution is to make a cast to TIMESTAMP but not in the location you suggested. The correct place when setting the scalars in the query executions. Using the example from above the solution is: 
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT Start_time FROM   table")
   .addScalar("Start_time", Hibernate.TIMESTAMP)
   .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Class.class);